# How to convert Optional<Object> to Optional<String>

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, java-11

I have this code in Java 11

```
Object a = getObjectOrNullIfNotAvailable();
String value = a==null ? null : a.toString();
```

I want to write this code using Optional, the best I could come up with is. I haven't tried running it but I suspect it will work

```
Optional<Object> oa = Optional.ofNullable(getObjectOrNullIfNotAvailable());
Optional<String> oas = oa.map(a -> a.toString());
String value = oas.orElse(null);
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this besides running map on the optional. I was hoping for something like the code below but this doesn't work

```
Optional<Object> oa = Optional.ofNullable(getObjectOrNullIfNotAvailable());
String value = oa.ifPresentOrElse(a -> a.toString(), a -> null);
```

Comment: To convert any `Optional<T>` to any other `Optional<U>`, use `optT.map(t -> convertToU(t))`

Comment: Optional is not a tool to avoid null checks. Your first snippet is what you should use. Optional has been designed to be used as a return type for methods, indicating they can return an "empty" value.

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"?  Please include the compiler error message, exception with stack trace, or incorrect output.  Also, what's wrong with calling `map`?

Comment: @rgettman It "doesn't work" because `ifPresentOrElse` is a `void` method, so cannot assign to `value`.

Comment: @Andreas Sure, I had copied the code and noticed that error and another error.  But generally we require the OP to be more descriptive with the error than "doesn't work".

Comment: Indeed, as @JBNizet commented, `Optional` is best used as a return value, a bit like returning an empty collection instead of null (allowing you to iterate over the empty collection without a null check).

Comment: The rational behind `Optional` is to force any user to do a null-check, since its impossible to get hands on whats inside an `Optional` without doing any check or throwing an exception. This pushes error detection to a much earlier stage than if you would use `null` and the user forgets the check and maybe forwards the value to other parties until the app crashes a day later at a different location when the value is finally used.

Comment: That's what I would do indeed – let your method return an `Optional` in the first place. If an absense of a return value would be a meaningful response, I would use `Optional`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating an Optional out of the return value of a method seems a bit awkward. Rather let your `getObjectOrNullIfNotAvailable()` method return an Optional in the first place. Then use the `map` operator to convert it in to a string. Here's how it looks.

```
Optional<Object> oa = someOptionalReturningMethod();
String value = oa.map(Object::toString).orElse(null);
```

For some reason if you can't change the return value of the method to an `Optional`, just leave the imperative solution using the ternary operator. Nothing wrong with that.

```
String value = a==null ? null : a.toString();
```

Comment: Besides return type, worth renaming the method instead of `getObjectOrNullIfNotAvailable` to something more meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
String value = Optional.ofNullable(getObjectOrNullIfNotAvailable()).map(Object::toString).orElse(null);
```

Otherwise, you can check if an Object is null and return in that case a String with "null" inside with String.valueOf(Object obj) or Objects.toString(Object obj). Eg.

```
  String value = Objects.toString(getObjectOrNullIfNotAvailable())
```

Comment: Notes regarding `Objects.toString()`: 1) is the same as `String.valueOf()` which works with older versions of Java; 2) both return the String `"null"` if the argument is `null` (not `null` as in questions code)

Comment: You are right, I will clarify this in my answerd. thanks

Comment: just some notes.... nothing wrong with the answer

Comment: This will fail if the method returns `null`. Use `Optional.ofNullable(…)` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` followed by `orElse` no need to separate them like so :

```
String value = Optional.ofNullable(a)
        .map(Object::toString)
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: I think you meant Optional.ofNullable . Thanks, this works