# Null pointer exception inside Optional.ofNullable()

Tags: java, option-type

I am trying to convert a set to string inside Optional.OfNullable method like:

```
test.setAbc(Optional.ofNullable(rule.getSampleSet().toString()).orElse(null));
```

but if `sampleSet` is `null` it will give me a `NullPointerException`.
can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue using `.map` method with `Optional`?

I know one traditional way of doing it by checking nullability beforehand:

```
if(rule.getSampeSet != null)
```

but I am much interested in knowing if we can do it in one line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Optional<Object> to Optional<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730799/how-to-convert-optionalobject-to-optionalstring)

Comment: Is it possible that rule is null?

Comment: no, rule cannot be null. i have checked it's null value then only called rule.getSampleSet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of calling `toString()` inside the `ofNullable`, you could `map` the optional to it:

```
test.setAbc(Optional.ofNullable(rule.getSampleSet()).map(Object::toString).orElse(null));
```

Comment: I don't know about ugly, but as a matter of style, I'd rather do `Optional.ofNullable(...)...ifPresent(test::setAbc)`.

Comment: I’m not arguing against any of the map calls. But I, stylistically, would rather call setAbc only if the optional is defined, and not in any case (which also causes the use of orElse). I may not have made myself clear ?